# Proving that the complement graph is not euler graph.

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

I came across with the following question from a book in Graphs (not in English):

> Let $T(V,E)$ be a tree with $n\geq 5$ vertices and exactly $3$ leafs.
>
> A. Prove that $T$ has exactly one vertex with degree $3$.
>
> B. Prove that the complement graph of $T$ (lets call it $T'$), is not euler graph.

I proved the first theorem but I think I found an example which disproves B:

Consider graph `T` with `6` vertices:

[image]

The complement graph of $T$ is:

[image]

I checked for a few time (I hope it's correct). There are exactly two vertices  $v_2,v_5$ that has an odd degree so it's an euler graph.

Where is my mistake?

Leaving that example, I tried to prove it by saying the following:
`T` has `3` lefts so those vertices in graph `T'` will have `n-1` degree. if `n` is even then we have `3` vertices that has an odd degree meaning that `T'` is not euler. But what can I say about the `n` even-case?

**EDIT**:

Euler graph is a connectivity finite graph which follows one of those conditions:

- Has exactly two vertices of odd degree. In that case its not a circle.
- All of the vertices with even degree. In that case its a circle.

Comment: The term "Euler graph" is sometimes used in the weaker sense for a graph in which every vertex has even degree. Have you checked the definition in your book?

Comment: @Servaes Hey, thanks for the reply. Please see my definition.

Comment: I think you are right, and the exercise in this form is incorrect.

Comment: Btw, you remark in the edit session is incorrect. A graph in which every vertex has degree $4$ is Eulerian, but not a circle.

Comment: @LeenDroogendijk I meant that every euler path in a graph that each vertex has an even degree, is a euler circle. At least that what it says in my textbook.

Comment: @LeenDroogendijk I suspect this is a translation problem, and that the intended word is 'cycle'.

Comment: OK, indeed I thought that circle was supposed to be an alias for cycle. Apologies for misunderstanding.

Comment: The term [Eulerian graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_path) **usually** refers to a graph which has a Eulerian **circuit**; equivalently, a connected graph with **no** vertices of odd degree. This stronger sense of "Eulerian" makes your exercise correct. If $n$ is even and not $K_3$, then $T$ has a vertex of degree $2$, so it has odd degree $n-3$ in $T'$. If $T=K_3$ then $T'$ is not connected.